# Google Oauth2 userinfo API not returning user's name data

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-api, userinfo

For the past couple months I have been using this url to retrieve a user's name and info after logging in with OAuth.

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json
```

This gave me JSON in the following format:

```
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "email": "name@gmail.com",
      "verified_email": true,
      "name": "First Last",
      "given_name": "First",
      "family_name": "Last",
      "link": "https://plus.google.com/12345",
      "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/123photo.jpg",
      "locale": "en"
    }
```

This morning, when my app hit this endpoint, it got JSON in the following format:

```
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "email": "name@gmail.com",
      "verified_email": true,
      "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/123/photo.jpg"
    }
```

I have not made any changes to the configuration in the developer console. Does anyone know what the cause of this problem could be?

Comment: Bschweer, have you checked my answer? Did it help or did you solve the problem in some other way?

Comment: Ján, I was able to solve this by updating the scope. My previous settings were working fine until the beginning of April. I do think the shutdown of Google+ had something to do with my issue.

Comment: How to update scope?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a different URL - the one from OpenID Connect, which is an OAuth2 extension for authentication and the `userinfo` endpoint is specified in [its RFC](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo).

```
https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo
```

The correct procedure is to get this URL from the [OpenID Discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) document ([Google doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery))

```
https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

and its `userinfo_endpoint` attribute.

The change of behavior of the endpoint you have been using may have something to do with Google+ being shut down. But that's just my guess.