# Google oauth2 endpoint does not return user profile info (name etc)

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, userinfo

I'm trying to use google oauth2 on my web service (golang), but can't get user profile info (given-name, family-name).

I'm trying various endpoints but every time get this kind of answer:

```
{
    "id":"*************",
    "email":"***@gmail.com",
    "verified_email":true,
    "picture":"https://***/photo.jpg"
}
```

In the same time google playground with this set of scopes returns this kind of answer:

```
{
  "family_name": "***", 
  "name": "****", 
  "picture": "https://*******/photo.jpg", 
  "locale": "ru", 
  "email": "****@gmail.com", 
  "given_name": "*****", 
  "id": "************", 
  "verified_email": true
}
```

How can i get the same answer in my web-app?
People on this site and in the internet advise to add profile scope, but I'm already done this.

Here is my code (shortened)

```
"golang.org/x/oauth2"
"golang.org/x/oauth2/google"

func init() {
    googleOauthConfig = &oauth2.Config{
        RedirectURL:  "*******",
        ClientID:     "*********",
        ClientSecret: "******",
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "openid"},
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }
}

var googleOauthConfig *oauth2.Config

//const oauthGoogleURLAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
const oauthGoogleURLAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo"
//const oauthGoogleURLAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
const oauthGoogleURLAPI2 = "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses"
//const oauthGoogleURLAPI = "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo"

func HandleGoogleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...

    oauthState, _ := r.Cookie(oauthstateCookieName)

    code := r.FormValue("code") 

    gtoken, err := googleOauthConfig.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)

    bearer := "Bearer " + gtoken.AccessToken

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", oauthGoogleURLAPI, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)

    gresponse, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(gresponse.Body)

    authContent := &AuthContent{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(contents, authContent)

    log.Println(authContent)

    ...
}
```

I'm also read this article [Google Oauth2 userinfo API not returning user's name data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541686/google-oauth2-userinfo-api-not-returning-users-name-data)
But result is the same : there is no profile info.

Thanks.

Update:
On the advice of the comment I slightly corrected code of "golang.org/x/oauth2" and get id_token.
When I checked this id token on jwt.io,  I saw all the data I need.
But I thought profile info should be retrieved through API request like this

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", <endPoint>, nil)
gresponse, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

In this example only standard go library is used and gresponse contains whole http response, isn't it? Why response does not contains fields that I need?

Comment: try and take the id token and put it in jwt.io.   Gtoken should contain an id token as well.  I am wondering if your library just isnt parsing the response correctly.

Comment: So, it looks like you are right. When I extract id_token from the depths of the library and check it through jwt.io, I saw all the data I need.
But I don't understand what's wrong.  I thought profile info should be retrieved through API request like
`req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", <endPoint>, nil)
gresponse, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)`. In this example only standard go library is used and `gresponse` contains whole http response, isn't it? Why response does not contains fields that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. That was my fault.
The structure that receive result was looking like this

```
type AuthContent struct {
    ID            string `json:"id"`
    Email         string `json:"email"`
    VerifiedEmail bool   `json:"verified_email"`
    Picture       string `json:"picture"`
}
```

This is why there is no fields like name in response.

Answer (score 0):

1. Handle error in `googleOauthConfig.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)`
2. Handle error in `http.DefaultClient.Do`
3. Handle error in `ioutil.ReadAll(gresponse.Body)`
4. Handle error in `json.Unmarshal`

And you may find the answer.

Also I remember I was always sending `access_token` as a query param:

```
response, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=" + token.AccessToken)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In original code (not shortened) I'm checking all returned errors like this
`if err != nil {
  log.Println("Code exchange failed: " + err.Error())
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
  return
 }`
But there is no any errors.
Also I'm tried sending querys with params instead of headers, but result was the same.